# how to use SPGooglePlacesAutocomplete in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, google-places-api

i am using [this](https://github.com/chenyuan/SPGooglePlacesAutocomplete)  objective-c wrapper to get the Google Places Autocomplete API result in search bar. i am able to use this sample .but when i copied all file in my project and want to use it i am getting lots of error. how to use it in iOS 8.to make  to get Google Places Autocomplete .[image] i am missing something here or what is this error .how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

import `uikit.h` into your header file.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

and remove all autorelease statement. they are not allowed in to arc.
that will rectify your general issues.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the one who created that CocoaPods repo you mentioned. It's out of maintenance, as you can find a better solution in [Google Places SDK for iOS](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete)